# Error 500 with client jquery rest and server java jersey-json running in tomcat 8

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, internal-server-error, jersey-client

I created a web service rest with jersey-json Java running in tomcat 8.0. My client is a phonegap app with java script and jquery. When I call the rest webservice in browser or soapui it's return ok. When I call with app (phonegap/javascript/jquery) it return server error 500:

```
{
  "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "syscall": "connect"
}
```

[Error in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH2mD.png)

Following is my source webservice server Java code:

```
package oneTrade.usuario;

import java.util.List;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/usuario")
public class UsuarioWS {

    @GET
    @Path("/listarUsuarios")
    @Produces("application/json")

    public List<Usuario> listarUsuarios(){
        return new UsuarioRN().listar();

    }

}
```

Following is my webservice client javascript code:

```
function json2(){
    $.ajax(
    {
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/oneTrade/rest/usuario/listarUsuarios",
        success: function(data){
            alert('Sucesso :' + data[0].cpf);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Erro ' + data.responseText + ' ' +data.thrownError+' '+data.status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show the error as logged in tomcat's logs

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2016:21:49:30 -0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 994
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Oct/2016:22:15:36 -0200] "GET /oneTrade/rest/usuario/listarUsuarios HTTP/1.1" 200 539
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Oct/2016:22:15:36 -0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1016
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Oct/2016:22:17:42 -0200] "GET /oneTrade/rest/usuario/listarUsuarios HTTP/1.1" 415 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Oct/2016:22:17:54 -0200] "GET /oneTrade/rest/usuario/listarUsuarios HTTP/1.1" 500 2168
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Oct/2016:22:18:26 -0200] "GET /oneTrade/rest/usuario/listarUsuarios HTTP/1.1" 200 539

Comment: Scary, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Sorry I was meaning from catalina.out

Comment: I'm running tomcat with eclipse, i didn't find the catalina.out file. Where do i find it? I don't know what's means catalina.out.

Comment: Ah in that case the error should be in your Eclipse console.  Basically a 500 error means that there is a `server-side` error.  This is what is important, not the Chrome error

Comment: I put the breakpoints in the beginning of code and the server is not called. I don't know what is happening. The eclipse's log records no show me nothing.

Comment: I'm using phonegap desktop to call my web service. I did many tests with client and server and don't find the error. Seems to me that phonegap is with issue. Does someone has any hint?

Comment: I found the error. The error was in the ripple's setting. I changed the option "Cross-Domain-Proxy" to "Disable" and the web service was called. Thanks for your entrist in help me.